# Proper settings for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, photo-editing

I am trying to get clear banners on a website. They don't look crisp and clear after compressing them (size 100 kb or so) for web.

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

1. The banner sizes are 1920px width by 600px height.
2. Here are my settings in PS when I "export as": https://prnt.sc/fz2pxo
3. After exporting I go to https://bulkresizephotos.com/ and scale the image to get it down to the 50kb - 200kb range for web.

What am I doing wrong exaclty? Why aren't the banners maintating their clarity?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are doing wrong is not knowing that the file size <=> quality relationship depends on what is the content of the file.

An image of that size, with just the word:

---

Hello!

---

Will weigh less than a full photo with a lot of small text. So you can not force compression too much.

If it is imperative to have lightweight banners make a **clean flat design**. Try png.

Comment: So  "hello" on blank white will be on the low end of the spectrum of file size and something like the one I uploaded will be higher on the spectrum. And unfortunately if it turns out to be a 300 kb file, for the sake of clarity, I have to deal with it. :( bummer but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem you are experiencing may lie with the distortion you have applied to the photograph.  Stretching an image like that is never going to look sharp, since you are basically mangling the pixels.

Instead of stretching the image, crop it to the aspect ratio you require.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of PS you use but I think that you can have better results by using the "Save for web" option instead of "export". There are various options to adjust the quality of the final image and you can also preview its size.

Comment: I have the latest version. I'll try that thanks!